# Вызов консоли из perl скрипта

Tags: скрипт, консоль, perl

Я хочу написать перл скрипт, который вызывался бы автоматически кроном и при вызове вызывал бы консоль. Как из перл скрипта вызвать консоль?

З.ы. Perl и Unix системы начал изучать недавно и знаю пока плохо. Не судите строго, если что не так.

Comment: $DISPLAY установлен правильно?
Xserver'у коннекции принимать разрешено?

Comment: честно говоря не могу ответить на ваши вопросы, т.к. не знаю. не могли бы вы подсказать как проверить то, о чем вы спросили?

Comment: Где вы хотите запустить консоль? На x-сервере? открыть виртуальный терминал на консоли?
Какая задача вообще стоит?

Comment: я хотел бы получить такой же результат, как и в результате ручного запуска скрипта (код я привел ниже в комментариях), т.е. увидеть окошко, или как вариант вызвать из кода терминал (но это вроде как через крон не получится сделать).

Comment: @alnasfire, я ниже в комментарии сделал шелл  скриптик. Попробуйте его через крон запустить (только лучше абсолютный путь к файлу с перлом пропишите).

Comment: возможно я что-то не так делаю, но у меня с шелл скриптом не получилось получить окошко. должен сказать, что с шеллом я совсем не знаком.

Comment: @alnasfire, строчки `Go` и `End` в логе (или как этот файл с результатами кроновского скрипта называется?) появились? А "кнопки" на экране не было?

Тогда проблема с правами доступа к X-серверу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Консоль вызвать из cron не получится - у Вас просто нет управляющего терминала, куда перенаправить ввод/вывод. А вот вызвать любую из команд или скрипт можно без проблем с помощью `system()` - [см. например](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands).

Comment: А можно ли из крона вызвать скрипт, который создает и показывает окошко с кнопкой?

Comment: @alnasfire, можно почти все. Для более предметного разговора опишите подробно, что именно Вы хотите сделать. 

--

Вот запускается скрипт по крону (допустим в полночь) (кстати, на каком сервере, у него какое локальное оборудование?). 

Где Вы хотите увидеть окошко?

Comment: на своей локальной машине, я хочу запускать по крону скрипт, который бы просто вывел бы на экран окошко с кнопкой.

Comment: Стандартного окошка с кнопкой не знаю, но думаю на перл есть библиотека (типа tcl/tk) для рисования GUI. 

Вот и напишите. Если разрешить всем пользователям работать с локальным Х-сервером (насколько помню надо смотреть xauth), то будет Вам окошко с кнопкой.

Вы для начала попробуйте из скрипта вызвать nohup xterm . Если прав хватает, то окошко (правда без кнопок) появится, а скрипт будет ждать его закрытия.

Comment: я нашел вот такой скрипт:

.

 #! /usr/bin/perl
use Gtk2 '-init';

$window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title("Hello world!!!!!");
$window->set_size_request(250,250);
 
$button = Gtk2::Button->new("Hello world!!!!!");
$button->signal_connect(clicked => sub { $window->destroy() });
 
$window->add($button);
$window->show_all;
 
Gtk2->main; 
0;


.

если его вызвать из консоли, то появится окошко и в нем во весь размер окошка будет кнопка. Но при вызове кроном скрипт окошко не выводит.

Comment: Вот я и говорил про man xauth и SEE ALSO в нем. Там много всего написано.

Кстати, я попробовал. Записал Ваш перл в t.pl, сделал sh скрипт

    #!/bin/sh
    echo Go
    nohup ./t.pl &
    echo End

и запустил его в фоне. Кнопка изобразилась! С кроном возится не стал, но понятно, что это осуществимо (в крайнем случае напишите на С враппер и установите ему **s флаг**).

Comment: А надо было бы повозиться... Cron предназначен для автоматизации вызова пакетных задач, которые не требуют ввода дополнительных данных. Весь вывод, который направляется на STDOUT cron автоматически перенаправляет на почту пользователя, заданную в переменной среды MAILTO. Если приложение требует ввода данных, оно немедленно получает EOF. 

Не надо возлагать на cron решение тех задач, для которых он не предназначен. Вы хотите периодически выкатывать на экран кнопку-напоминалку? Сделайте обычную прикладную программу, организуйте в ней прерывание по таймеру, пустите ее в фоновом режиме и радуйтес

Comment: @voldemarus, если этот комментарий мне, то при желании (и рутовом доступе) можно сделать почти все (вплоть до модификации ядра (здесь это не потребуется)).